# Thread runs fine when I use it in onCreate but App crashes when I start Thread onClick?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, server

I have a cards game for LAN play. The code works fine on PC but now I shifted my code to Android. I'm getting a weird problem.

I'm hosting a game on a Thread by starting it on Button Click which takes no. of players. Heres the onClick method:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            if(txtPlayers.getText().toString()!=null){
                int pl=Integer.parseInt(txtPlayers.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Server Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new Thread(new GameServer(pl)).start();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter Players",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

In the above code I start a runnable Interface of the GameServer which goes like this:

```
public class GameServer implements Runnable {
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private int maxClientsCount,port;
private  ClientThread[] threads;
private  Turn turn;
private  SumGame sg;
public final String TAG = "com.codechefamit.min";

GameServer(int players){
    maxClientsCount=players;
    port=7777;
    turn=new Turn(maxClientsCount);
    sg=new SumGame(maxClientsCount);
    threads=new ClientThread[maxClientsCount];
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG,"Listening.....");
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    int count=0;
    while (count<maxClientsCount) {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                if (threads[i] == null) {
                    threads[i] = new ClientThread(clientSocket, threads,turn,count+1,sg);
                    count++;
                    Log.i(TAG,count+" Connected");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"Starting Clients");
    for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        threads[i].start();
}
```

}

GameServer starts a new Thread for every Client Request. This code runs fine when I start GameServer Thread in My MainActivity onCreate() but when I copied the same code to a Button Click my App crashes.

The Client who hosts the game also joins the game from MainActivity. This works when I start GameServer thread inside onCreate. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
01-12 20:34:21.252  22250-22741/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2419
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.codechefamit.min_sumandroidclient.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:57)
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Comment: posted the stack trace it shows a NullPointerException at ClientThread which should not happen as I have initialized it..
One thing that I noticed is that the app only crashes when the Host is the last one to connect.. Otherwise it works fine

Comment: "which should not happen as I have initialized it" - but looks like it happens. Anyway, trace your code with the debugger to see what exactly is null and why.

Comment: Since they are in an array, my first impression would be that one of them is not initialized.

Comment: Im not sure about the logic here but one approach you can use is that adding initialized threads to another array and traverse start them instead of  looping static MAXLOOPCOUNT

Comment: What's the statement at ClientThread.java:57?

Comment: ClientThread.java :57 is a println statement which uses other threads OutputStream to print something on other Client.... OutputStream is initialized and the code runs without errors when I debug it ..

Comment: Found the bug... One Thread was using other threads OutputStream before it was initialized which gave an error only sometimes cause both the threads were seperate.. I initialized the OutputStream in the constructor now... Thanks everyone!!